# Is it possible to pay from an Android App without a server of mine?

Tags: android, paypal, stripe-payments, payment

I want to purchase from my Android app, and I want to pay with an API like Stripe, or Paypal, but if I understood well I have to have a server side where the payments are done, and I only have to use the API to get the tokens.

My question is if I must implement the server, or I could do the payments against the Paypal or Stripe Servers?

Comment: You need a server there's no way around it from an Android App as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is use a service like [Commence Payments](https://www.commencepayments.com/) or the [PayPal Button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_create-pps-buttons/) but because these are built in HTML you'll need to host it in a webcontrol.

Comment: You can do the Commence Payments route without a web service, just using Stripe-Android and a web request. You can email Commence Support (aka me) for the documentation for it.